Can I create stack driver alert policies off of log analytics queries?
I can't find anything in the docs that just says yes or no.
I'm not talking about log based metrics I'm talking about Log Analytics queries that create time series graphs: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/analyze/charts
When you create log based metrics your creating new metrics, but Log Analytics can query logs and return a time series graph on the fly- can I use these queries in alert policies?
It would be much more powerful because these queries include historical data and are much more dynamic.
